# How to have multiple references for a single node in a tree structure using Rust

Tags: reference, rust, tree

Trying to create a tree in rust with the following struct:

```
pub struct Node{
    pub children: Vec<Box<Node>>,
    pub parent: Option<Box<Node>>,
    pub value: f32,
    //.....
}
```

To build a new node the following function is used:

```
pub fn build_node(parent: Option<Box<Node>>)-> Node{
    Node{
        children: vec![],
        parent,
        value: 0.0,

    }
}
```

When trying to add nodes, for example with:

```
let mut root_nd = tree::build_node(None, 5, state);
let mut next_nd = tree::build_node(Some(Box::new(root_nd)), 2);
root_nd.children.push(Box::new(next_nd));
```

There will be errors, because I am borrowing for example `root_nd` and then trying to add `next_nd` to the `root.children` list, and even if there wasnt this error I would still need to have a reference for `next_nd` after adding it to the children of `root_nd`. I know that in rust it is not possible to have several mutable references simultaneously for the same element. So the question is how is it possible to make a tree-like data structure, with bi-directional references in rust? In my head this is a conflict since rust does not want multiple references but I need a node in the middle of the tree to be referenced by both his parent node and his children nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been meddling with trees in Rust for quite a bit recently. To work with trees in rust, you will need [`Rc` (A single-threaded reference-counting pointer)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) so that you can have multiple ownership. And you'll also need `RefCell` to enable interior mutability since multiple mutable references are not allowed by the compiler. With `Rc` and `RefCell`, you can define your *TreeNode* as following:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub struct TreeNode {
    pub children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub value: f32,
}
```

And here is one way to create two nodes that references each other:

```
impl TreeNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(value: f32) -> Self {
    TreeNode {
      value,
      children: vec![],
      parent: None
    }
  }
}

let mut root_nd = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(5.0)));
let mut child_nd = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(2.0)));

child_nd.borrow_mut().parent = Some(root_nd.clone());  // use Rc::clone to create a new reference to root_nd
root_nd.borrow_mut().children.push(child_nd.clone());
```

Since we use `Rc::clone` to create a new reference to the node, `root_nd` and `child_nd` are not consumed and can still be accessed in later program.

More examples on Trees in Rust:

- [leetcode 95 Unique Binary Search
  Trees](https://github.com/leopsidom/leetcode-rust/blob/master/95.unique-binary-search-trees-ii.rs)
- [leetcode 94 Binary Tree Inorder
  Traversal](https://github.com/leopsidom/leetcode-rust/blob/master/94.binary-tree-inorder-traversal.rs)
- [leetcode 100 Is Same
  Tree](https://github.com/leopsidom/leetcode-rust/blob/master/100.same-tree.rs)

Comment: There are other solutions, like using arenas to store the nodes and use indexes or ids as "pointers" (look for example for id-arena).

Comment: So every time I want to use it, I should pass the full rc<refcell<..>> to the function and then use `borrow_mut()` to extract and access its elements?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Normally a node is represented as `let node: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>`. And when you pass the reference to the function, you probably need to clone it so that the current reference is not moved. i.e. `somefun(node.clone())`. And to access its elements, use `borrow` (immutable) or `borrow_mut` (mutable).

Comment: @Psidom I got it working after some grinding! Thank you. Just one more thing, why do you like to use option on the <Rc<RefCell? In your use case it can be passed as None? Because I did not need it yet.

Comment: Use `Option` here b/c the parent can be None, and btw `None` by itself is of type `Option` so if a value can be `None`, then its type must be `Option`.